# Karate framework. Disable xml conversion to json

Tags: testing, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, karate

I need to send an XML doc to my service to test but undortunately Karate converts my XML to JSON. How can i disable such conversion? The service under test understands only XML. I use the 0.5.0 Karate version

Answer (score 1):

Actually the issue gone after upgrading to 0.7.0 edition of Karate

Comment: Thanx for your suggestion but i have a two-days delay to do this.

Answer (score 1):

use xmlstring instead of def. This will ensure the xml is passed as such without any conversion